scp function in .zshrc file can't handle multiple files
Just wrote a fuction in the .zshrc file which looks like
function scptc() { scp -r ./$1 fa223jd@loginfu.fub.de:/dss/dssfs02/lwp-dss-0001/pn49qu/pn49qu-dss-0000/systems/water/H2O-64/dat/$2 ; }

it works fine as long as I just transfer one file or directory. If I transfer more than one, lets say
scptc {rgyr.mat,plot_rgyr.m} plots/

It reads the second file as the name, the first file should be renamed to.
I've tried
{<files>} , \{<files>\}, '<files>'

But nothing works.
